# Constructing an equivalent Pushdown Automaton

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I'm working on an exercise (not relevant for evaluation) that involves constructing an equivalent nondeterministic stack machine from a given machine with epsilon-transitions. However, I'm having trouble understanding Definition 2, specifically the line

[image]

Could someone please explain this line and guide me via hints through the steps to construct the equivalent nondeterministic stack machine? I'm not asking for a solution, just for help.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]